# Is there a way to calculate the hamming distance between a constant string and strings in a txt file?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hamming-distance

I need to calculate the hamming distance between a constant string and a txt file full of other strings, each on their own line in the file. Then to put all the strings with the same distance from the constant into an ArrayList? Ex: All strings with Hamming Distance 2 would be in a list, all with distance 3 would be in another list etc).

I know how to calculate the hamming distance between 2 strings, but not a constant and 50+ other strings in a txt file.

Any help would be great, I am new to programming so thank you!

I have read in the entire txt file into an ArrayList as my first step.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all strings have the same size. You could use a HashMap to keep in track of currently existing hamming distances, key is hamming distance, val is their indexes in List<List> result.

```
public static int hammingDistance(String str1, String str2) {
    int index = 0, count = 0;
    while (index < str1.length()) {
        if (str1.charAt(index) != str2.charAt(index)) {
            count++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static List<List<String>> getHammingDistances(String constantString, List<String> strs) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sizes = new HashMap();
    for (String str : strs) {
        int distance = hammingDistance(constantString, str);
        if (!sizes.containsKey(distance)) {
            sizes.put(distance, result.size());
            List<String> newDistances = new ArrayList();
            newDistances.add(str);
            result.add(new ArrayList(newDistances));
        } else {
            result.get(sizes.get(distance)).add(str);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    strs.add("abcde");
    strs.add("abcdf");
    strs.add("bbcde");
    strs.add("bcdef");
    List<List<String>> result = getHammingDistances("abcde", strs);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to implement this Using JavaFX with the string constant being the selected value of a ComboBox could this methodology be implemented (with a few changes).

Comment: JavaFX also supports Java ArrayList and HashMap, it does not make any significant differences, you just need to take care of input and output's format and types. I suppose you know how to design JavaFX, ComboBox and etc..